# Complex Borel Measure and Bounded Variation Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, bounded-variation

3.29 Theorem in Folland states that: If $\mu$ is complex Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x])$, then $F \in NBV$. Conversely if $F \in NBV$, there is a unique complex Borel measure $\mu_F$ such that $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x])$.
NBV={F is of Bounded Variation: F is right-continuous and $F(-\infty)=0$}.

Now all, of sudden I am confused/completely lost.  My professor writes that:

1. If $F(x)= \chi_{[a, b)}$, then it is in BV and right continuous so it is in NBV?
   and 
   $u_F= \delta_a-\delta_b$.  I have no idea how $u_F= \delta_a -\delta_b$.  How was this formulated/come up with? I have no idea how $u_F$ was determined
   Also I'm not exactly sure what is meant by $\delta_a$ and -$\delta_b$

Does Dirac measure in this case mean, $\delta_a$ mean$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c@{,\quad}l} 1 & x=a \\ 0 & x \neq a. \end{array}\right.
$$
$\delta_b$ mean$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{c@{,\quad}l} 1 & x=b \\ 0 & x \neq b. \end{array}\right.
$$ ? Or is this wrong.

Why then is $\mu_F=\delta_a- \delta_b$? I'm very anxious why I don't understand how this was derived/ why it is true.

2. Like wise, my professor writes that 
   if $F(x)= \arctan(x)$, for $x>0$, 
   $0$ otherwise
   then $F \in$ NBV.
   and $d\mu_F= \frac{1}{1+x^2} \chi_{x>0} dm$. (dm meaning respect to Lebesgue measure).
   Then how do I get $\mu_F$?
   I'm honestly not sure why the expression for $d\mu_F$ is true.  Now I'm very anxious why I'm not understanding these formulations.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as guessing what $\mu$ is it would be very helpful to know some basic probability theory.  If you are not familiar with probability theory it is best to just verify that the statement made by the professor are right. BTW, $\delta_a$ denotes the measure defined by $\delta_a(E)=1$ if $ a\in E$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So the measure is 1 at the point a?

Comment: I don't understand why $\mu_F=\delta_a-\delta_b$?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, this $F$ is NBV. The $\delta$'s are indeed Dirac measures, however, as such, they take measurable sets as values, rather than function values.

$$\delta_a(A) := \begin{cases}1, &A \ni a\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \qquad (A \in \mathcal{B}\mathbb{R})$$

$\mu_F$ is now the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure based on NBV function $F$. In order to show this, we need to show that
$$\mu_F((c,d]) = \delta_a((c,d]) - \delta_b((c,d]) =  F(d)-F(c) \qquad (c, d \in \mathbb{R}, c < d)$$
It is probably best to consider different cases:

(i) $c < d < a < b \Rightarrow \mu_F((c,d]) = 0 - 0 = F(d)-F(c)$

(ii) $c < a \leq d < b \Rightarrow \mu_F((c,d]) = 1 - 0 = F(d)-F(c)$

(iii) $a \leq c < d < b \Rightarrow \mu_F((c,d]) = 1 - 1 = F(d)-F(c)$

(iv) $a \leq c < b \leq d \Rightarrow \mu_F((c,d]) = 0 - 1 = F(d)-F(c)$

(v) $a  < b \leq c < d \Rightarrow \mu_F((c,d]) = 0 - 0 = F(d)-F(c)$

As the set of intervals $\{(c,d] : c, d \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a semiring, we can now apply Carathéodory's extension theorem and know that the $$\mu_F(A) = \delta_a(A) - \delta_b(A) \qquad (A \in \mathcal{B}\mathbb{R}).$$

Maybe one hint to give you an intuition, also towards the second question: If you have an NBV function, you can compute a something like a generalised "derivative". "Derivative" refers to the measure-theoretic fundamental theorem of calculus. Like in the case above, this "derivative" may be represented by a measure rather than a function - especially in cases like in 1., where $F$ is clearly not differentiable. It actually is a function, if $F$ is absolutely continuous (with respect to the Lebesgue measure).

2. The latter is the case here. In particular, we have $$\mu_F(A) = \int_{A} F'(x)\mathrm{d}x \qquad (x \in \mathcal{B}\mathbb{R})$$ Also, $\arctan'(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$, (x > 0)

\begin{align*}F(x) &:= \begin{cases}\arctan(x), &x > 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \qquad (x \in \mathbb{R})\\
F'(x) &= \begin{cases}\arctan'(x), &x > 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}1/(x^2 +1), &x > 0\\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} \qquad (x \in \mathbb{R}) \qquad (x \in \mathbb{R})
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for the very detailed answer.  My question is, I sort of get the proof but I'm not too confident in the intuition behind why$\mu_F= \delta_A=\delta_B$.  Like if I saw a Question determine: $\mu_F$ for the characteristic function given in question 1, what is the quick intuition that tells me that it is $\delta_a-\delta_b$? Is there a quick way to see/know that the answer is $\delta_a-\delta_b$? My teacher seemed to think it was obvious, does it have to do with support of the measure. Just would like to know the quick intuition, thanks.

Comment: Or further I'm not sure why the derivative is represented as the difference of two measures in this case where F is not differentiable? Why is this so?, thanks

Comment: The measure is concentrated, where the variation of $F$ lies. $F$ is constant aside from the points $a, b$.  Hence, there is no variation whatsoever aside from $\{a,b\}$. In $a$ there is positive variation, in $b$ negative variation. For such piecewise constant functions, this may be a good intuition.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, one last question , but why is there positive variation in a and negative variation in b. I don't understand what positive variation and negative variation mean in this circumstance, or what variation means in this case

Comment: Intuitively: In $a$ the function increases  ($F(a-) = 0 \uparrow 1 = F(a)$), in $b$ it decreases  ($F(b-) = 1 \downarrow 0 = F(b) $).